# Data migration from site5 to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've a Rails 2.1.2 App hosted on [site 5](http://www.site5.com/).

This App is running since 2 years and I want to migrate the site on [heroku](http://heroku.com/).

No pb to install the site on heroku, but what about the data?!

What is the best strategy to export from site 5 (I've phpMyAdmin) and then import to heroku?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export the data to your local system as SQL dump from phpMyAdmin, import it into your development database and then use the built-in Heroku db tools (based on Taps) to import into production:

```
heroku db:push
```